# How to find the number of subsets with length m in an array with length n without rearranging elements

Tags: arrays, sorting, subset

Let say I have Array(string, doesn't matter) of size `n`.
For example int array: `int[] MyArr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`
Array length is 5, I want to know number of subsets with length of 3 elements from this array without rearranging elements of this array, it is easy for small arrays to calculate it but I would like to know general formula for array of `n` elements and subset of `m` consecutive elements.
For example above it is

> {1, 2, 3}
>
> {2, 3, 4}
>
> {3, 4, 5}

not `{1, 2, 4}` or `{2, 5, 1}`, only consecutive elements

**Note: array shouldn't be sorted**

Comment: `n-m+1` because if you want consecutive sequences the first will start at position 1, the next at position 2, ...

Comment: Can you say how to calculate number of subsets that contain ith element, for situation above: number of subset that contain second element i.e. 2 and has length of m(subset has)

Comment: `min(m, n-m+1, i, n-i+1)`. But as this seems like a homework question, I let the reasoning for that forumula up to yourself ...